# Convert unusual PHP date format from VARCHAR to DATETIME in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I have many date entries in a VARCHAR field in my MySQL DB.
PHP is formatting them like this:

Sun, 25 Jan 2015 18:20:04 +0000

I know how to insert dates/times into a correct MySQL DATETIME format going forward (once I correct the PHP code), but I want to run a SQL query to convert the existing DB entries.
After much searching on here, I've found many people suggesting something like this:

```
UPDATE MyTableName SET Date2=str_to_date(Date1, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S');
```

However, that seems to just place "NULL" in all of the rows in my new column.
Is this because MySQL cannot handle my particular PHP date format with str_to_date?
If so, can anyone suggest any other ways of updating the field.  I don't mind using PHP or MySQL queries to achieve this.

Many thanks.

Comment: Your format string doesn't match the input string AT ALL. `Sun, 25 Jan` would be `%a, %e %b`. since you're telling mysql the input string should look like `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`, it's of course not finding any matches in your date strings. and note that php doesn't have a "date format". it has unix timestamps, and any formatting is something YOU as the user chooses.

Comment: Also, should it be %i for minutes instead of %m?
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-str_to_date/

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still getting NULL in every field using this:    UPDATE Files SET StartDate2=str_to_date(StartDate, '%a, %e %b %H:%i:%S');   or   UPDATE Files SET StartDate2=str_to_date(StartDate, '%a, %e %b');       or even UPDATE Files SET StartDate2=str_to_date(StartDate, '%a, %e %b %H:%i:%S +0000');      I was thinking it needed to match the output string (rather than input) hence my original error..